# How do I decide my specialization in cyber security?

Tags: research, career, iot

I have done web security and interested in learning mobile security, IOT security, malware analysis etc. Will doing all of this make me "Jack of all but master of none". I have a limited time to devote how do I decide

Comment: Have a good read through the questions here, especially those on professional-development and career to help you decide for yourself. As Kamic said - we can't tell you :-)

Answer (score 4):

Only you can decide your fate. Follow what makes you happy, where your passion is, and as you evolve through your career that drive will change multiple times making you a better candidate to employers. Network with others, goto conferences, and keep on learning!